# Ebay API SSL? tls 1.2

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, ebay-api

I know PayPal and SagePay are upgrading their SSLs to tls 1.2 encryption. 
Has anyone heard anything about Ebay following the trend?

I'm looking through their dev site and can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are finally getting around to it now.   [Ebay API moving to TLS 1.2](https://go.developer.ebay.com/security-update-support-tls-12-api-endpoints)